# Inhibit mouse interactions for certain svg child elements

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

Here is an svg with a circle drawn on it:

```
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .on("mouseover", function() { console.log("callback");} );

svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", 50)
     .attr("cy",50)
     .attr("r",20)
     .attr("fill","red");
```

Why does `mouseover` fire when I mouse over the `circle`? I assume because its a child element of its parent `svg`?

But I'd like to inhibit this action. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The arguments on the mouseover function don't seem to pass in the event, so I came up with this solution instead.

```
svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
     .on("mouseover", function() {
         var event = window.event;
         if (event.target.nodeName === "svg") {
             console.log("callback");    
         }
     });

svg.append("circle")
     .attr("cx", 50)
     .attr("cy",50)
     .attr("r",20)
     .attr("fill","red");
```

Comment: how can I target a certain svg class?  event.target.nodeName === "svg.classname" doesn't seem to work.  Neither does just ".classname".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to inhibit pointer interactions set [pointer-events](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/interact.html#PointerEventsProperty)="none" on that element.

```
.attr("pointer-events","none")
```

Answer (score 0):

Container elements don't trigger mouse events in SVG.  The event will only get triggered when you mouse over any of the child graphical elements it contains.